# Unable to get new changes from master to my local branch

Tags: git, github

When I give `git diff localBranch:file master:file`, it is showing the difference between two files across specified branches. But, when I give `git merge origin/master` from my local branch, those differences are not reflecting to my local file. Also, It is showing "Already up-to date"

Note: I manually made changes and merged my branch with master and  pushed my local branch to remote repo, so I don't have any proofs or evidence to show

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps you followed before this issue occured?

Comment: Have you fetched -- 'git fetch'?

Comment: I was in master,
1. git checkout -b new_branch.
but, in new branch, the code which was in master was not there. So,  I did,
"git merge origin/master" from my branch